# Selenium get_attribute('src') of an image returns Base64 instead of an url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using selenium to automaticlly download several images from google images, cause all the other solutions previously made i found on internet were too slow or weren't working, but now i need the extract the source of the image, but when i try using element.get_attribute('src') it returns the base64 of the image,even tought when i search for the xpath on the chrome devtools the src attribute of the tag it's actually a url

[image: this is a screenshot of the element in devtools]

Code trials:

```
        for i in range(n):
            element = self.wait.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/img')))
            src = element.get_attribute('src')
            print(element)
            self.download_file(src,keyword)
```

EDIT:

I actually tried what some of you said and instead of downloading the image, i converted the base 64 into a image and saved it, which was amazingly faster than saving using requests and the URL, but guess it was more a problem with the Google script than with my code, cause sometimes my code broke cause src actually returned a URL, in the end, i had to make a two different functions, one if src returned a url and other if returned base64

Comment: Can't you just use the base64 of the image and save that, instead of getting the URL and downloading that?

Comment: maybe url is in different element - and maybe you should use better XPATH (without all these `div` but with classes or IDs. Or it uses JavaScript to replace values and it needs some time for this. Or server sends different code for different browsers/devices.

Comment: without minimal working code it is hard to test this problem.

Comment: Please provide page url to have us investigate further .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *src* attribute you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[alt='Letter A AC - Decortiles'][src]"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='Letter A AC - Decortiles' and @src]"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I'm actually using this right now, self.wait in my code is actually webdriverWait, I'm used to program in java too, so i have the habit of declaring too much variables in def __init__()

Comment: _I'm actually using this right now_: Nice to know. _self.wait_: minor adjustment, should be okay with you. _habit of declaring too much variables in def init()_: It isn't any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could retrieve the actual image URLs from another search engine [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) using the following code:

```
search_query = 'what you want to find'
num_images = 1
driver_location = '/put/location/of/your/driver/here'

ser = Service(driver_location)
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)

# searching the query
driver.get(f'https://duckduckgo.com/?q={search_query}&kl=us-en&ia=web')

# going to Images Section
ba = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--images']")
ba.click()

# getting the images URLs
for result in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.js-images-link')[0:0+num_images]:
    imageURL = result.get_attribute('data-id')

    print(f'{imageURL}\n')

driver.quit()
```